# Microsoft Teams push notification is blank for some adaptive cards

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We have a Microsoft Teams project running on a Node server using botbuilder v4.14.0, among other things.  This project sends adaptive cards to Microsoft Teams users in a direct message, and for each adaptive card we set a `summary` text for the purpose of rendering in the push notification the end user receives.

Something along the lines of this suggestion, we set the message summary field:

```
var response = MessageFactory.Text(string.Empty);
response.Attachments.Add(cardAttachment);
response.Summary = "Hello custom notification";
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
```

The problem we have is that sometimes this appears correctly in the push notification, but other times it appears entirely blank.  What's more, the name of the app is different in the push notification - for notifications with the correct `summary`, the name of the app is pulled from our Azure Application Service metadata, but when the `summary` is missing the name is somehow pulled from the Teams app manifest file.

[Example of different notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyAJh.png)

In both cases, the payloads are normal adaptive cards, delivered exactly through the same code.  We explored any differences we could find between the two different adaptive cards and found nothing meaningful.  One just worked while the other just didn't.

Digging in further, we found that by modifying the size of the payload, we could make an adaptive card that failed to render a notification start working.  To make an adaptive card render the `summary` field in the push notification, we added additional text until a threshold was exceeded.

For instance, measured in bytes, we found that one particular adaptive card would start to render the `summary` field after 1888 bytes, but would not render the `summary` at 1887 bytes.  However, another adaptive card, structurally different than the first example, would render the `summary` at 1781 bytes, but not at 1780.

Why does the `summary` start rendering at one payload size vs a smaller one?  Why is the payload size inconsistent between the two payloads?  Why are the names different?  So many opaque questions.

Ultimately, how do we send adaptive cards so that they always render the `summary` in the push notification?

Edit: In testing, it appears that push notification summaries appear correctly for Teams Web, Desktop, and Android notifications.  They do not work consistently for Teams iOS notifications.

Comment: Could you please confirm in which platform you are facing the issue? Is it in MS Teams Desktop or web client?

Comment: I'll edit the description to add that information, but the push notification delivery I'm testing is for Teams on iOS.  I'll review other platforms to check if the behavior is the same.

Comment: · Login to Teams in iPhone -> Click on settings
· Click on “About”
· Enable Developer Preview
· Teams client might restart.
· Check whether Developer preview enabled or not (It must be enabled before proceeding to next step)
· Long press on empty adaptive card in iOS-> Click on Inspect Card
It opens popup window with card JSON.

Check the card JSON if it is missing any mandatory properties. Usually it fails to render in iOS because of missing required properties.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the direction @SubbaReddiTummuru, I enabled this and it's a great way to debug the content of adaptive cards.  Unfortunately it was not exactly helpful in this case, as upon reviewing the JSON of the cards, I didn't see the `summary` field on any of them, even verifying one that had the summary notification on the Desktop notification but not the iOS notification.  What's also odd is that for that card, we send the adaptive card version as 1.4, but on iOS it's received as 1.2.  Very odd indeed, but also likely a non-issue.

Comment: @MattCollins - There is a bug raised for 'Summary string ignored for adaptive cards with small payload in iOS' issue and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any further update. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Thanks for referencing this bug report https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/5080, by chance is there any update on when this might be resolved?

Comment: @MattCollins - Sorry for delay in response.
We are actively checking the updates on this issue with engineering team and let you know, if we have any.